# Ensuring coverage for all enum values in map

Tags: c++, enums

Say I have the following:

```
#include <map>

enum class Thing {Zero, One, Two};

class Metadata {};

std::map<Thing, Metadata> extra_info;

void foo() {
    extra_info[Thing::Zero] = Metadata();
    extra_info[Thing::One] = Metadata();
    extra_info[Thing::Two] = Metadata();
}
```

I would like to ensure that all tags of `Thing` are accounted for in `extra_info`, in the event that a new tag is added, like `Thing::Three`.

I considered always having a tag at the end, `LastTag`, and iterating from `0` to `LastTag - 2` and verifying that those keys exist in the map, but this seems kludgy. A way to accomplish this at compile time would be best, but I can see this not being possible, at all.

In C#, it's a simple thing to use reflection to get all the enum values, then iterate over these. I think it's telling that I can't find an answer for this with the C++ tag, but I can find answers for Java and C#... Which makes me think this isn't possible.

Comment: It's common when using enums to use the "last" approach you specify: having a dummy value at the very end that becomes the constant for one-past-the-end of the valid values. While it seems kludgy, it's what we've done since forever in C/C++, so there is a lot of precedent for taking that approach.

Comment: You don't even have to iterate. If you know that the value of last is let's say `n` then you can just check that the size of the map is equal to `n`. This will work because the map requires unique keys and it will only accept valid enum types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentinel values in enums have been part of many projects to indicate the number of enum values or to delimit a range of user-available enums from the system-defined ones.

In your case you can exploit the fact that a map has unique keys and add a sentinel value (strictly not part of the enum):

```
enum class Thing { Zero, One, Two, Three, EndSentinel };

class Metadata {};

std::map<Thing, Metadata> extra_info;
typedef std::map<Thing, Metadata>::size_type map_type;

void foo() {
    // Can't forget these values
    extra_info[Thing::Zero] = Metadata();
    extra_info[Thing::One] = Metadata();
    extra_info[Thing::Two] = Metadata();
    extra_info[Thing::Three] = Metadata();
}

int main() {
    foo();

    assert(extra_info.size() == (map_type)Thing::EndSentinel);
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/FcKvBB)</kbd>